# How to implement User Alerts when users signup using auth Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-alertdialog

Hello I'm trying to find out how to implement alerts when users are trying to login or signup to my app.

The below code is my "auth-service-dart' page and I am trying to display the message error that shows in the console from (print(e)) per the code below to my signup page where I have the signup button, so the result I want is the app shows alerts if the users make errors like adding an email that was already added or wrong email.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthService {
  static final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static final _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  static void signUpUser(
      BuildContext context, String name, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      FirebaseUser signedInUser = authResult.user;
      if (signedInUser != null) {
        _firestore.collection('/users').document(signedInUser.uid).setData({
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'profileImageUrl': '',
        });
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, signedInUser.uid);
        //Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId = signedInUser.uid;
        //Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static void logout() {
    _auth.signOut();
    //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
  }

  static void login(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wat are u getting here print(e);

Comment: In the console, I am getting print the default error message from auth.service, I want that message to show in a container in my signup page

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **showDialog** provided by flutter;
here is a simple code for that in your **widget**

```
 showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error happend'),
          content: Text(// your errro code here),
          actions: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Text(language['ok']),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Yes, I know about that widget, that's the one I can use however the issue is that I dont know how to call the value (print (e)) to the showdialog in another page...how would you do that?

Comment: you need to store it in the state

Comment: I tried to use setState but it is not valid to use, is there another option to call it?

Comment: I tried to use like this:   } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _error = e.message;
      });
    }